# Is git rebasing the wrong branch?

Tags: git, rebase

I have three branches:

```
master
dev
feature
```

My branch `master` is up to date. I want to rebase my branch `feature` with
`master`

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

But at the beginning I see:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: ajout model widget desc + stats
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
```

`ajout model widget desc + stats` is the first commit on this branch.
So the rebase is using the wrong version of my branch.

The result is a lot of conflits, and my file that I have committed is gone.

Exemple :

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
            $this->createWidget('samples/footer','content', array('channeltitle'=>$channelTitle));
=======
            $this->createWidget('samples/desc','desc', array('channelTitle' => $channelTitle));
            $this->createWidget('samples/statistics','statistics', array('channelTitle' => $channelTitle));
            $this->createWidget('samples/footer','footer');
>>>>>>> ajout model widget desc + stats
```

he want to rebase the head of the branch master with the wrong commit...(ajout model widget desc + stats)

I searched for a solution to rebase my branch with the lastest commit.

```
| * fac92fe (HEAD, origin/feature, feature) work better
| * a366488 works in AJAX !
| * f5d120e appel ajax dans la vue
| * c1f8360 ajout model ajax bestVide, FeaturedChannel (no cache active)
| * 211fda0 ajout widget network
| * 4d1c2a5 social link
| * c511472 ajout model widget desc + stats
|/
| *   2f8ddcc (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merge branch 'dev'
| |\
|/ /
| * 0c859da dev Channel/Network + fix Artifice
|/
| * 41c0cfb (origin/update_channel, update_channel) update
| * 66015b6 ajout bannerimg
| * 1433e90 ajout entete script
| * 619d850 ajout dossiet script crontab
| * 8c4b2c8 channel inactive + simplification
| * 37c453c modif network
| * b764ddb fisrt version script update_channel
|/
*   5676028 Merge branch 'generalmodels'
|\
| * da10f84 Return JSON in utf8
| * 10f7897 good job bro
| * 3eadddc config grunt
:
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all` please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't actually look wrong.

Your output is expected

1. First rewind all your commits from `feature`
2. Then apply all the commits from master. This cannot fail and gives no particular output.
3. Then apply all your commits, in order, starting with `ajout...`

In your case it gives conflicts. It's not unusual so you need to resolve them in the editor of your choice, then **continue the rebase**. In your current state the rest of the commits are still waiting to be applied, they are not missing.

1. Fix conflicts. For all files run `git add <file name>`
2. Then `git rebase --continue`
3. Do this until the rebase is complete.

If it feels like havoc you can always abort the rebase with `git rebase --abort`

Comment: Well if i do `git rebase --continue` my file on branch `feature` are erase and i have the new folder from `master` ...

Comment: Before doing --continue, what does `git status` tell you?

Comment: lot of file doesn't exist in my new branch. The most important is that my folder from the branch feature are gone when i want to rebase. He rebase with my fisrt commit of the branch feature, not the last

Comment: Git will rebase all of the commits, in order, starting with the first.

Comment: see my edit the exemple, maybe you can understand the problem

Comment: That is a normal conflict. Decide what you want to keep and make sure to remove all lines with <<<<<, ==== or >>>>> as they are indicators of where the conflict occurred. Git is fine with keeping them but your code will of course not run. Then run `git add <file name>`. Do this until all files that shows up with `git status` under the section "files in conflict" or similar are gone. Then `git rebase --continue`. It should try to apply "social link" next, possibly causing more conflicts.

Comment: Awesome ! thx, i didn't know that he pass each commit of the branch. I learn something ! Maybe edit your post to clarify this point :)